# missing { inserted

Tags: pdftex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,layout}
\usepackage{feynmf}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\topmargin -2.0cm \oddsidemargin -0.04cm \evensidemargin -0.04cm
\textwidth 16cm \textheight 24.0cm
\parskip 7.2pt
\begin{document}
\title
    {Física Hadrónica\\
    Master Inter-universitario en Física Nuclear\\
    Universitat de Barcelona}
\author{Martí Florit Gual (UB)\\ \\
    Profesora: Laura Tolós}
\date{}
\maketitle
\newpage
\section{Calcular el potencial nucleón-nucleón debido al intercambio de un escalar.\\
\textit{Ayuda}:\\
{(a)} trabaja en el sistema centro de masas. Si $\vec{p}_1$ y $\vec{p}_2$ son el momento de las partículas iniciales 1 y 2, respectivamente, y $\vec{p^'}_1$ y $\vec{p^'}_2$ los momentos de las partículas finales 1 y 2, entonces podemos definir  $\vec{p}_1=- \vec{p}_2=\vec{p}$ y $\vec{p^'}_1=- \vec{p^'}_2=\vec{p^'}$. Con estas definiciones, introducimos los siguientes vectores: $\vec{k}=1/2(\vec{p}+\vec{p^'})$ y $\vec{q}=\vec{p^'}-\vec{p}$.\\
{(b)} trabaja en la aproximación no relativista: $E+M$ \~ $2M$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\~
```

is a command for a tilde accent you presumably intended `$E+M \sim 2M$`

Unrelated but you should be using a list environment not `{(a)}`

Also

```
\section{Calcular el potencial nucleón-nucleón debido al intercambio de un escalar.\\
```

should be

```
\section{Calcular el potencial nucleón-nucleón debido al intercambio de un escalar}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you have written primes as

```
p^'
```

The correct way is either

```
p'
```

(or occaisionally

```
p^\prime
```

).

Anyway you are misusing the section heading horribly.  Here is a suggested improved version:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,layout}
\usepackage{feynmf}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\topmargin -2.0cm \oddsidemargin -0.04cm \evensidemargin -0.04cm
\textwidth 16cm \textheight 24.0cm
\parskip 7.2pt
\begin{document}
\title
    {Física Hadrónica\\
    Master Inter-universitario en Física Nuclear\\
    Universitat de Barcelona}
\author{Martí Florit Gual (UB)\\ \\
    Profesora: Laura Tolós}
\date{}
\maketitle
\newpage
\section{Calcular el potencial nucleón-nucleón debido al intercambio de un escalar.}

\noindent\textit{Ayuda}:

{(a)} trabaja en el sistema centro de masas. Si $\vec{p}_1$ y
$\vec{p}_2$ son el momento de las partículas iniciales 1 y 2,
respectivamente, y $\vec{p'}_1$ y $\vec{p'}_2$ los momentos de las
partículas finales 1 y 2, entonces podemos definir  $\vec{p}_1=-
\vec{p}_2=\vec{p}$ y $\vec{p'}_1=- \vec{p'}_2=\vec{p'}$. Con estas
definiciones, introducimos los siguientes vectores:
$\vec{k}=1/2(\vec{p}+\vec{p'})$ y $\vec{q}=\vec{p'}-\vec{p}$.

{(b)} trabaja en la aproximación no relativista: $E+M\sim 2M$
\end{document}
```